# Disable automatic reply in Spring JMS

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms

According to Spring reference [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#jms-annotated-response), method annotated with `@JmsListener` and have a non-`void` return type will have the result of the invocation encapsulated in a `javax.jms.Message` and sent either in the destination specified in the `JMSReplyTo` header of the original message or in the default destination configured on the listener.

If no destination is found then an `InvalidDestinationException` will be thrown.

Is there a way to disable this behavior of automatic reply ?

**EDIT**

I'm using an `@Around`Advice to log the result of the execution that's why i need to have a return type on my listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning `null` from the method if it has a return type, will disable reply processing.

You can detect the presence (or not) of a replyTo by adding a `@Header` parameter to the method.

Or, add a `@SendTo` with a destination to use if there's no header.

**EDIT**

Since you are using an advice to log the return value, you can simply return `null` from the advice, instead of the result of `invocation.proceed()`.

Comment: I need to add a return because i'm using AOP with `@Around` advice to get the result and log it.

Comment: So, return `null` from the `Advice` instead of the result of `invocation.proceed()`.

Comment: That did the trick. I should have thought about it. i'll update my question to include the need for a return type. you can update your answer and i'll accept it.